# HTMLagilitypack table class

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have a HTML source where there is a extra space and I do not know how to process it

```
<table  class="Details">
```

If I do,

```
HtmlNodeCollection tabledetailnode = hdoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class=\"Details\"]");
```

I am not getting any nodes. How can I handle this?

Comment: Silly question: does it work without the extra space?

Comment: It should work, and in fact, it works for me. There must be something else in your code.

Comment: It should work.  You have something else going on...maybe you are not parsing the text you think you are parsing.

Comment: Is there a way of distinguishing <table  class="Details"> (2 spaces) and <table class="Details"> (one space) and <table width="400" class="Details">?

Comment: @newbieCSharp - Nope. This is seen as the same HTML. PS: please use the @<SO user name> markup so the user to whom you're writing is notified.

Answer (score 1):

this might help

```
List<string> test = new List<string>();
try
        {

            HTML_Node.Get_HTML_Nodes($"{URL}", "//table[@class='Details']//tr").Result.ForEach(n =>
            {


                List<string> values = n.ChildNodes.Where(cN => cN.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Element).Select(e => e.InnerText.Trim().ToLower()).ToList();

                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(values[0]))
                {
                // skip to the next node if there is no value 
                }
                else
                {
                 // add the value [0 ] to your list 
                    test.Add(values[0]);


                }

            });


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
       return test ;
```